# unable to initialize parse sdk in php laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, parse-platform

Is it possible to integrate the parse sdk to the php laravel framework? I am having problem in initializing parse from the laravel project. Can i get link to a sample project please?

Answer (score 0):

Check these Open Source Projects

[LaraParse](https://github.com/HipsterJazzbo/LaraParse)

[Laravel Parse](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Parse)

Hope this helps :)